# How to control click of event in fullcalendar?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I am developing in `cordova angularjs`.

I used [this tutorial](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar?files=1) to integrate a full calendar in my project

My goal is: i want that when I click an event in my fullcalendar a popup is displayed.

**my controller:**

```
facebookExample.controller("evenementCalendarController", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location,$ionicPopup,$state,$http,$cordovaCalendar,uiCalendarConfig) {    
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/evenements/'+$localStorage.idInfoEvent+'/l', { params: {fields: "titre_annonce,date_evenement",format:"json"} }).then(function(result) {   
        var d= new Date(result.data.date_evenement);
        $scope.alertOnEventClick = function( date,allDay,jsEvent, view) {
            $scope.alertMessage = (' was clicked ');
        };

        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar:{
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                lang: 'fr',


                dayClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
                eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,

                events: [
                {
                 title: title,
                 start: d,
                 allDay: true,
                 //rendering: 'background',
                 backgroundColor: '#00CED1',
                }
                ],
                 color: 'red',   // an option!
                 textColor: 'black',
                calendar:{
                   lang: 'fr'
                }

            }
        };
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'array.length')
http://localhost:36994/lib/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:98 
!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'sources.length')
http://localhost:36994/lib/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js:63
```

And my popup won't display. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after the last event option:

```
backgroundColor: '#00CED1',
```

This is the last property for that event object, so it should not be followed by a comma.